# Cola de mensajes en C

Tags: posix

La idea es enviar un mensaje  y recibirlo a traves de una cola de mensajes.
De momento lo he puesto de forma simple para entender como funciona. Pero al ejecutar me sale un error:

> bad file descriptor

en la funcion `mq_send`.

Aunque el identificador de la cola usado en la función `mq_send` es el mismo usado para crear la cola (en la funcion `main()`). Agradezco cualquier pista.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <mqueue.h>
    #define MSG_SIZE 4

    mqd_t idcola;

    void  *enviar(void *argg){
        int prior=0;
        unsigned int dato=0;
        char *buffer;

        while(1){
            buffer=(char*)&dato;
            if (mq_send(idcola, (const char *)buffer, MSG_SIZE, prior) == -1){
                perror("ENVIAR");
            }
            dato=(dato+1)%100;  
        }
    }

    void *recibir(void *argg){
        int dato;
        char buffer[4];
        unsigned int prior;

        while(1){

            if (mq_receive(idcola, &(buffer[0]), MSG_SIZE, &prior) == -1){
                perror("RECIBIR");
            }

            dato=*(int*)&(buffer[0]);
            sleep(2);
            printf("Dato Recibido =%d\n",dato);
        }
    }

    int main(){
        pthread_t th1,th2;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        struct mq_attr attrq;
        //atributos de la cola de mensajes
        attrq.mq_flags=0;
        attrq.mq_maxmsg=10;
        attrq.mq_msgsize=MSG_SIZE;

        pthread_attr_init(&attr);

        mq_unlink("/pc");
        idcola=open("/pc",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,(S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH),&attrq);

        pthread_create(&th1,&attr,enviar,NULL);
        pthread_create(&th2,&attr,recibir,NULL);

        pthread_join(th1,NULL);
        pthread_join(th2,NULL);

        printf("Fin\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: has probado a hacer un debug y ver exactamente lo que estás pasando?

Comment: No lo puedo probar ahora, pero diría que `idcola`, que inicializas con el resultado de `open`, no coincide con el tipo `mqd_t`. ¿Has probado a abrir el fichero con `mq_open` en lugar de con `open`?

Comment: @ordago Si tienes razon, alli estaba el problema.tenia que abrirlo con mq_open. Gracias.

Comment: @Bart, si quieres puedes hacer una respuesta a tu propia pregunta indicando como lo has resuelto y aceptar la respuesta para cerrar el hilo y que quede por respondido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error era usar una llamada al sistema open() que se usa para abrir un fichero en vez de 
 la funcion mq_open() que es la mas indicada para abrir y/o crear una cola de mensajes.
lo cual generaba un descriptor de fichero inadecuado para la funcion mq_send().